# git sign notes for push to central server

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-notes

How do I add a note and sign it?

Using BitBucket, repo has
Verify Commit Signature
Reject commits and tags without a verified GPG signature
enabled.

My build job adds a note to the commit that has just been built:

```
16:10:53  + git notes append --file=notes.txt
16:10:53  + git push origin 'refs/notes/*'
16:10:54  remote: Signed commits and tags are enforced for this repository.        
16:10:54  remote: 32bba27cbe6 was not signed.        
16:10:54  To https://bitbucket.XXX.com/scm/YYY/ZZZ.git
16:10:54   ! [remote rejected]     refs/notes/commits -> refs/notes/commits (pre-receive hook declined)
16:10:54  error: failed to push some refs to 'https://****:****@bitbucket.XXX.com/scm/YYY/ZZZ.git'
[Pipeline] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that when you merge strategy for a pull request is "--squash" then BitBucket will not sign the new commit.  So you cannot add a note if you have "verify commit signature" set.

Now even if you use ff-only merge, and the head of the branch is signed you still cannot add a note if you have enabled.

Verify Commit Signature
Reject commits and tags without a verified GPG signature